# Derivations of Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

In my book of electrodynamics, the Maxwell equations are always used for specific conditions (electrostatics, magnetostatics, …). But nowhere I see a complete derivation of the equations. Maybe it will sound compendiously: how can we derive this equations?

Comment: Derive from what? An action principle?

Comment: Maybe you meant that you do not see the general form of Maxwell's Equations that covers all specific conditions?

Answer (score 9):

You can't. You can justify them from physical experiments and observations, complemented with some mathematical handling for consistency, but the Maxwell equations are ultimately axioms - they are postulates that we put forth from the beginning, and they get their validity from the predictive and explicative ability of the EM theory we build from those equations to match and explain experiments.

(That said, there does exist a "deeper" set of axioms, in classical field theory, from which the Maxwell equations can be derived, but (i) it will likely look outlandish to you, and (ii) it raises exactly the same questions about how you 'derive' those axioms as the Maxwell equations raise.)

Answer (score 1):

To ask such a general foundational question is to start an infinite regress of "Why?" questions. What should count as the starting point that it, itself, does not fall under the "Why?" spotlight too?

Since you left it open, I'll improvise.

**Step 1: Kirchhoff's Laws**
Suppose you have to two vector fields, $$ and $$. The first is a surface density that describes currents, such that the total current $I_S$ passing through a given surface $S$ is $I_S = \int_S ·d$, where $d = (dy∧dz, dz∧dx, dx∧dy)$ is a unit surface element that points in a direction orthogonal to $S$. The second is a line density that describes voltage drops, so that the total voltage drop $V_P$ along a path $P$ is given by $V_P = \int_P ·d$, where $d = (dx, dy, dz)$ is an line element of the path $P$.

The wedge product $(\_)∧(\_)$ is in the sense of Grassmann algebra of differential forms. We won't be making any significant use of it, but it's just a more or less standard way to represent the integrands of the integral operators.

We shall assume...

1. **Law Of Currents**: The total current passing through the closed surface $∂V$ comprising the boundary of a region $V$ is zero: $I_{∂V} = 0$.
2. **Law Of Voltages**: The total voltage drop around the closed loop $∂S$ comprising the boundary of a surface $S$ is zero: $V_{∂S} = 0$.

In integral form, the respective equations are:
$$\int_{∂V} ·d = 0, \hspace 1em \int_{∂S} ·d = 0,$$
which are held to be true for all suitably-defined volumes $V$ and surfaces $S$. By "suitably-defined", we can mean, for instance, that the respective regions be simply-connected, compact (both, in the sense of topology) and are "measurable" (in the sense of measure theory).

Applying the relevant theorems (Stokes', Gauss', etc.), we can turn the boundary integrals into integrals over the "bulk" of the regions in question:
$$\int_V ∇· dV = 0, \hspace 1em \int_S ∇×·d = 0,$$
where $dV = (dx∧dy∧dz)$ is an element of volume in the region $V$.

Owing to the arbitrariness of $V$ and $S$, we may infer from this that the integrands are each zero:
$$∇· = 0, \hspace 1em ∇× = .$$

**Step 2: The Electromagnetic Energy** (a.k.a. The Potential For Voltages)
Since voltage drops are curl-free, we can define a potential $φ$ for it, that's in Volts, by simply setting $φ() = 0$ at some arbitrary point $ = $ that we label as the origin, $$ and then defining $φ$ as a function of $,t$ as $φ(,t) = -\int_^ (',t)·d'$ along any path that goes from $$ to $$. Its path-independence is ensured by the condition that $V_P = 0$ along any closed loop $P$.

From this, we derive the equation $ = -∇φ$.

The voltage $φ$ is what we already recognize as the potential energy per unit charge, hence the name.

The term "electromagnetic energy" being used here is entirely separate from what is elsewhere known as the electromagnetic energy density. I'm just using it for rhetoric's sake.

**Step 3: The Units And $μ_0$**
We will adopt a convention to establish units for electrodynamics. We will set 1 Henry to 10000 km, or about the distance between the equator and the poles. Once you have the Henry, you can express all the other units in terms of it. To disentangle our new units from the meter-second-kilogram units, we will adopt the conversion factor as a coefficient $μ_0 = 1 \text{Henry}/(10000 \text{km})$. After having arguments and debates with contemporaries about all the factors of $4π$ that will later crop up, we'll agree to stick in an extra factor of $4π$ and, instead, set $μ_0 = 4π×\text{Henry}/(10000 \text{km})$. That's more or less the historical line of progression of the coefficient. The line was broken in 2019, however, when both it and That Kilogram Bar In Paris were taken off the A-list in favor of of $h$ (Planck's constant) and $e$ (the positron charge). So, now it is only approximately equal to said value, $e$ encodes the new standard for electromagnetic units, and $μ_0$ is left dangling. But, we'll still keep it around for later use.

**Step 4: The Electromagnetic Momentum** (a.k.a. The Potential For Currents)
Since the total current is divergence-free, we can define a potential for it that is, likewise, divergence-free. Let $$ be the unique solution to the following:
$$∇^2 = -μ_0 , \hspace 1em ∇· = 0.$$
In terms of dimensions, it has the units of momentum per unit charge, so that it resembles a "potential momentum", much the same way that voltage provides a potential energy per unit charge.

**Step 5: The Magnetic Induction And Magnetic Field**
Though $$ is divergence-free and has zero flux through any closed surface, the same is not true for its circulation around a closed path. The integral $\int_P ·d = 0$ need not vanish along any path $P$, nor around any loop. This provides us what is known as the "loop" representation of the potential. The circulation around the boundary $∂S$ may be written as:
$$B_S = \int_{∂S} ·d = \int_S ∇×·d,$$
which has units of Webers, which we identity as "magnetic charge/flux". By comparison, the unit for potential is Volt = Weber/second.

The surface density of this field as identify as the "magnetic induction" $ = ∇×$.

It, too, has zero divergence, $∇· = 0$, by virtue of the identity $∇·∇×(\_) = 0$, however, the same is not so for its curl, which may be written as:
$$∇× = ∇×(∇×) = ∇(∇·) - ∇^2 = -∇^2 = μ_0 .$$
As such, we find that the field, that we shall label, $ ≡ /μ_0$, behaves as a kind a kind of potential for currents in its own right, with $∇× = $, in that the total current flux $I_S$ through any surface $S$ may be expressed as:
$$I_S = \int_S ·d = \int_S ∇×·d = \int_{∂S} ·d,$$
as a circulation of $$ around the periphery $∂S$ of $S$. We will call this the "magnetic field".

**Step 6: The Wave Speed Axiom**
We assume that there is a speed $c$ that is characteristic of the vacuum ... how and why, we feign no hypothesis. It may be that there should be a single frame of reference identified with the vacuum, itself; or that perhaps the speed is in some sense "absolute". We take no sides on the issue; other than to note that the speed somehow a fundamental property of empty space.

Instead, we will calibrate our units in terms of this speed, by identifying a meter as 1/299792458 of the distance traveled this speed in one second. That is: $1 \text{meter} = c×\text{second}/299792458$.

Correspondingly, we may define a coefficient
$$ε_0 = \frac{1}{μ_0c^2}$$
that corresponds to what we called the permittivity of free space.

**Step 7: The Electric Field And The Electric Displacement**
The electric field $$ may be recovered from the potential drop $$, by subtracting off the time rate of change of the current potential:
$$ =  - \frac{∂}{∂t}.$$
Unlike $$, it will not be curl-free, but will instead satisfy the following equation:
$$∇× = ∇× - ∇×\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right) = -\frac{∂}{∂t}(∇×) = -\frac{∂}{∂t}.$$

We may then define another field "induction" field $$ that bears the same relation to $$ that $$ does to $$, but with the permittivity $ε_0$, instead of $μ_0$:
$$ = ε_0 ,$$
that we term the electric "displacement". It has the units of charge-density multiplied by distance, so that it measures - in some sense - how much separation and polarization of electricity exists per unit volume.

**Step 8: The Charge And Current Sources**
The displacement field serves as a means to separate off the contribution of the field and its potential from the current $$ to arrive at a current density $$ that represents the convection of electrical charge, and a density $ρ$ for electrical charge, itself, which we define as:
$$ =  - \frac{∂}{∂t}, \hspace 1em ρ = ∇·.$$

With the contribution from the field subtracted out, the equation $∇· = 0$ that came out of the Kirchoff Law for currents now becomes the *continuity equation* for charge and its convection:
$$∇· + \frac{∂ρ}{∂t} = 0.$$

**Step 9: Maxwell's Equations With The Vacuum Constitutive Laws And Coulomb Gauge**
Together, this yields Maxwell's Equations in the following form:
$$
 = ∇×, \hspace 1em  = -∇φ - \frac{∂}{∂t} \hspace 1em⇒\hspace 1em ∇· = 0, \hspace 1em ∇× + \frac{∂}{∂t} = ,\\
∇· = ρ, \hspace 1em ∇× - \frac{∂}{∂t} =  \hspace 1em⇒\hspace 1em ∇· + \frac{∂ρ}{∂t} = 0,
$$
with the constitutive laws for the vacuum
$$ = ε_0 , \hspace 1em  = μ_0 ,$$
and the "Coulomb Gauge":
$$∇· = 0.$$
As a point of reference and comparison, Maxwell used the Coulomb gauge in his treatise.

**Step 10: The Constitutive Laws For Material Media**
To arrive at constitutive laws for material media, we would have to apply any of the several well-known averaging procedures that have been posed from time to time, to yield effective or averaged values for one field, each, from the two pairs $(,)$ and $(,)$ in terms of the other fields of each pair.

A general use-case consists of media that possess at least one frame of reference in which a constitutive law for the effective fields can be posed, which is "isotropic":
$$ = ε , \hspace 1em  = μ ,$$
where the wave speed $V = 1/\sqrt{εμ}$ for the material need not coincide with The Wave Speed $c$ for the vacuum.

We call this the Frame Of Isotropy.

In other frames of reference, the Frame Of Isotropy is moving at a relative velocity $$, and we assume $|| < V$ ... not so much out of necessity, but convenience, leaving the open the possibility of media that are moving faster than their wave speed - even sparse media approaching a vacuum.

In a non-relativistic setting, the constitutive laws in a moving frame transform to the following:
$$ = ε( + ×), \hspace 1em  = μ( - ×),$$
which - taken in conjunction with Maxwell's equations - is equivalent to the equations posed by Lorentz, Hertz' and Maxwell (after the Thomson correction $-×$ is included).

The relativistic form of these include corrections on the left-hand sides:
$$ + \frac{×}{c²} = ε( + ×), \hspace 1em  - \frac{×}{c²} = μ( - ×).$$

On account of this, if $εμ = 1/c^2 = ε_0μ_0$, *regardless of what $ε$ and $μ$ may individually be*, and if $|| < V$, then these equations are provably equivalent to the "stationary" version, where $ = $. To prove this, just substitute:
$$ - ε = ε×( - μ), \hspace 1em  - μ = -μ×( - ε),$$
and use the condition $εμ||^2 < 1$.

In general, if $ = ε×$, $ = μ×$ and $εμ||^2 < 1$, then $|| ≤ ε||||$, $|| ≤ μ||||$, from which follows that $|||| ≤ εμ||^2||||$, or $\left(1 - εμ||^2\right)|||| ≤ 0$. Divide out by the factor $1 - εμ||^2 > 0$ to get $|||| ≤ 0$. Since $0 ≤ ||||$ is already the case, then $|||| = 0$, from which it follows that either $ = $ or $ = $. By virtue of the starting conditions, it follows that they both are.

Applied to the equations above, with
$ =  - μ$ and $ =  - ε$, yields the $ = $ form of the constitutive laws: $ = μ$ and $ = ε$.

For non-relativistic theory, the correction terms are absent, and there is no way to escape attaching a frame of reference to the vacuum. The $$ vector can't be made to go away, like it can for the vacuum in the relativistic case ... unless, that is: $εμ = 0$. In that context, it bears noting that zero-permittivity media ($ε = 0$) actually *do* exist. I don't know about zero-permeability media ($μ = 0$).

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can do a charge balance using continuity equation
$$-\nabla \cdot I/Area=- \nabla \cdot J=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

We know V=IR so J=Conductivity×E substitute to get a relation that might be used later with a partial of time.

Better way to get Gauss first law Q=CV C=epsilon A/D, V=ED does mean the first law $$ \epsilon \nabla \cdot E = \rho$$. Or use Coulombs law F=EQ=KQ1Q2/R^2 . E=KQ/R^2 charge density is del dot E

For magnetic fields in=out number of lines in= number of lines out
$$\nabla \cdot B=0 $$

We also know F=EQ+QV × B so F/Q= E+ V × B
Maybe you can use the material derivative along a stream line to be constant E and B
$$\frac{DE}{Dt}=\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}+ c \cdot \nabla c $$
The partial is a sine wave

You can try the rest of the derivativion yourself and I'll check it out